# ExtJs 3 - Add listener

Tags: extjs

I would like to accomplish:

- When some item in the ComboBox is selected hide some other field in the form or a complete div.

This is my ComboBox:

```
var typeIDcombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: 'Type',
        name: 'typeid',
        store: typeIdData,
        displayField:'name',
        valueField: 'typeid',
        hiddenName: 'typeid',
        typeAhead: false,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText:'Selecteer het type link',
        forceSelection: true,
        selectOnFocus:true,
        allowBlank: false,
        value: 'Selecteer een type',
    });
```

I have add listeners to my var form = new Ext.FormPanel. But this does not work.

```
listeners: [{
    'select' : function(field,nval,oval) {
     alert(field);
    }],
```

Does someone know a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you add a `select` listener to `Ext.FormPanel`, when it should for `Ext.form.ComboBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the listener on FormPanel is not necessary cause the FormPanel will not fire any 'select' events on its own events. You should add the listeners on the components inside the FormPanel to listen the specified events fired by the component.

For your case, it is simple as the follows:

```
var typeIDcombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'typeid',
    store: typeIdData,
    displayField:'name',
    valueField: 'typeid',
    hiddenName: 'typeid',
    typeAhead: false,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText:'Selecteer het type link',
    forceSelection: true,
    selectOnFocus:true,
    allowBlank: false,
    value: 'Selecteer een type',
    listeners:{
         select:function(field, newVal, oldVal){
             if(newVal == 'HIDE_SOMETHING'){
                  Ext.getCmp('fieldId').hide();
                  Ext.getCmp('formId').doLayout();

             }
             else if(newVal == 'SHOW_SOMETHING'){
                  Ext.getCmp('fieldId').show();
                  Ext.getCmp('formId').doLayout();

             }
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for. The object notation does work very well. I used the array-notation as sra describes but that one did not work. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
typeIDcombo.on('select', function(combo) {
    if (combo.value == 'ABC') { 
        Ext.getCmp('field').show();
        Ext.getCmp('form').doLayout();
    } else {
        Ext.getCmp('field').hide();
        Ext.getCmp('form').doLayout();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks MMT! This works great but I prefer the object like Bigfei described.

Answer (score 2):

As Warung wrote, that should do it:

```
var typeIDcombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'typeid',
    store: typeIdData,
    displayField:'name',
    valueField: 'typeid',
    hiddenName: 'typeid',
    typeAhead: false,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText:'Selecteer het type link',
    forceSelection: true,
    selectOnFocus:true,
    allowBlank: false,
    value: 'Selecteer een type',
    listeners: [{
        select : function(field,nval,oval) {
            alert("Hit");
    }]
});
```

Comment: It does not work with a array notation. The object like Bigfei writes does work. Thanks for helping me in the right direction!

Comment: select should not be in quotes!